# Swift decodable with unknown coding key and value

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I want to decode the following object from the server

```
{"USD":6385.74,"JPY":715249.73,"EUR":5582.36}
```

but I want to use a decodable struct with unknown key and value.Is this possible?

Regards,

Spyros

Comment: Decode a dictionary (`[String:Double]`).

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:Double].self,from:data)
print(res["USD"])
```

which will enable you to decode any key

Comment: ok so there's no meaning to create a decodable struct or class simple [String: Double] will work.

Comment: @sger you should be careful in using it , it doesn't give the optimum solution in all cases

Answer (score 0):

When I work with JSONs that are not fully known (as in I know all the possible keys and need all of them) I used SwiftyJSON library: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

It's much easier to work with than the built in JSON decoder

in your case it would be:

```
var jsonString = "{\"USD\":6385.74,\"JPY\":715249.73,\"EUR\":5582.36}"
let json = JSON(parseJSON: jsonString)
```

then you can do a bunch of stuff like iterating over keys

```
for (key, value) in json {
    if let currency = key.string {
        print (currency,value)
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation in https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but I double checked the code and there was a small mistake there in initializing the JSON object - fixed now

Comment: Not my downvote, but please note that SwiftyJSON is considered obsolete now that Swift has a proper way of dealing with JSON, with the Encodable/Decodable protocol.

Comment: @Moritz - thanks for the feedback but I disagree, Swift JSON is still strongly typed. In this example if the JSON had another element that was not String:Double the entire code will fail and the decoding would return nil. Swift built in JSON is still a pain if you work with resources that are more variable and not straightforward

Comment: Ok so how do you actually do it? This answer directs to someone to a library which hides the details. Useful if you don't want to learn anything, but not useful if you do.

Comment: @JaredH I think if you're interested in writing a JSON parser that's outside the scope of this answer, and to be honest, probably my capabilities. I did google and find this answer which I thought was interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063888/124737

Comment: @RonSrebro it is neither beyond your abilities or the scope of this answer. Swift makes parsing JSON very straightforward. Look into the `Codable` protocol.