# Swift How to decode JSON without knowing the key name?

Tags: json, swift, decode, decoding

I have json that looks something like this:

```
"events": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "something"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "something2"
    },...
}
```

Is there any way to decode this type of JSON where I dont know the name of the key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53140765/1187415.

Comment: Yes, the "1" and "2" will keep changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well probably if you don't know the key you are ok to store it like a string. So a solution then could be using a Dictionary like so:

```
struct EventsResponse: Codable {
    var events: [String: Event]
}
```

Comment: Thak you so much, I didnt think of that!